# Copying contents of a text file to another file

Tags: c

I'm trying to copy contents of a text file to another text file but my code doesn't work. I've recently started to work with text files so i can not find where the problem is and i don't know how can i solve it. Can you help me please? Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintFileContent(FILE* fptr);
void copy_file(FILE* fptr, FILE* fptr2);
int findNumberofChar(FILE* fptr);

int main() {
    FILE *first, *second;
    
    first = fopen("first.txt","r");
    second = fopen("second.txt","w+");
    
    PrintFileContent(first);
    copy_file(first, second);
    PrintFileContent(second);
    
    return 0;
}

void PrintFileContent(FILE* fptr){
    
    char txt;

    txt = fgetc(fptr);
    while(txt != EOF){
    printf("%c", txt);
    txt = fgetc(fptr);
    }
}

void copy_file(FILE* fptr, FILE* fptr2){
    
    char temp;
    
    temp = fgetc(fptr);
    while(temp != EOF){
    fputc(temp, fptr2);
    temp = fgetc(fptr);
}
}
```

Comment: `char temp;` -> `int temp;`

Comment: `while(txt != EOF){` in `PrintFileContent` - upon exit of the loop, where is the file pointer `fptr` referring? And did you do *anything* to rectify that before invoking `copy_file` ? Perhaps a `rewind` is on the near-future agenda.

Comment: You forgot to `rewind(fptr);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'main' program should rewind the file pointers, before reusing them. Otherwise, the file points are at the end of the content, and the copy_file and the 2nd printFile will not do anything:

```
int main() {
    FILE *first, *second;
    
    first = fopen("first.txt","r");
    second = fopen("second.txt","w+");
    
    PrintFileContent(first);
    rewind(first) ;
    copy_file(first, second);
    rewind(second) ;
    PrintFileContent(second);
    
    return 0;
}
```